# Apache user-agent blank in log

Tags: apache-2.4

In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_log_agent agent
```

/var/log/apache2/access_log_agent just shows a hyphen for every visit:

```
-
-
-
```

Why am I unable to log user-agent? I am running Apache 2.4.25 on Debian 9.6.

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally was dropping user-agent at a network level.

Comment: Could you provide more details?